# Fast way to get information from a huge logfile on unix

Tags: loops, unix, grep, logfile

i have a 6 GB applicationlogfile. The loglines have the following format (shortened)

[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ABC;**type=m**
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ABC;**set_to_TRUE**
[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-HHH;type=m
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-HHH;set_to_FALSE
[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ZZZ;type=m
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ZZZ;set_to_FALSE
[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-WWW;type=s
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-WWW;set_to_TRUE

I have a lot of session with more then these 2 lines.
I need to find out all sessions with **type=m** and **set_to_TRUE**

My first attempt was to grep all sessionIDs with type=m and write it into a file. Then looping with every line from the file (1 sessionID per line) trough the big logfile and grep for sessionID;set_to_TRUE

This method takes a loooot of time. Can anyone give me a hint to solve this in a much better and faster way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe this question belongs to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site.

Comment: oh, for sure...can i shift my question to the Unix & Linux site?

Comment: I am not sure. More powerful creatures should be called. Until that you may look on [that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94464/search-and-filter-text-on-large-log-files) which may be related to your problem.